# New vectors for representations of GSp4 with nontrivial central character

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

Roberts and Schmidt have developed a theory of new vectors for generic irreducible smooth representations of $\operatorname{PGSp}_4(F)$ for $F$ a nonarchimedean local field, using the "paramodular subgroups".

Has this theory been generalized to representations of $\operatorname{GSp}_4(F)$ that have nontrivial central character (and thus don't factor through $\operatorname{PGSp}_4(F)$)?